# What is a good jQuery plugin to show a contact form on hover over an image/icon?

Tags: jquery, forms, tooltip, contacts

I'm in need of a jQuery(/AJAX) script that shows a contact form when i hover over an image,icon or link of some kind. Something like a tooltip with contact form support?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't sound very usable or accessible of the user...

Comment: You are right, i meant on click instead of on hover. That's much better right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery UI here is an example;

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

When you click on 'create user' in the example, it will pop up a form

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks i think i can use this!

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try this

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/